# What should I do with damaged leaves on my Money Plant?

Tags: plant-health, pruning, leaves, vines, damage

Some leaves on my money plant, [Epipremnum aureum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epipremnum_aureum), have been damaged by rats.

Should I cut them or leave them? If cutting them is good for the plant, from where should I cut the leaves?

Here are some pictures of the leaves:

Leaf 1:

[image]

Leaf 2:

[image]

Leaf 3:

[image]

Leaf 3 (close-up):

[image]

Leaf 4:

[image]

Leaf 5:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah, so that's what you mean by Money Plant - this one's more commonly known as Devils Ivy or Pothos, but is, as you now say, Epipremnum aureum. It is on the list of plants toxic to rats, so again, I'd be very surprised if the damage has actually been caused by rats. That said, cut back the plant to remove badly damaged or unattractive areas - the odd hole in a leaf isn't much to worry about, but you can cut back to a leaf node, that is, cut the stem back to where there's a healthy leaf. If the growth is trailing over the ground, then you need to stand the plant on something so that doesn't happen.

Comment: So I have to cut the main stem till the healthy leaves? Or the damaged leaf stem? It's kinda confusing. Is it poisonous to squirrels too? because they are rodents too. But if yes, how come I still see squirrels running energetically?

Comment: Toxic doesn't necessarily mean causing death - this plant is likely to cause burning mouth and upset stomach rather than death. If you have a damaged leaf stem (like the one you;'ve shown) it may heal on its own - if it starts to look bad, then cut it back past the damaged point.